# How do I put string format in querystring

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi I have date in database which is storing in below format : **04/02/2014 00:00:00**

Now I need to retrieve this date by removing zeros using string format that is in below format :
**04/02/2014**.

Below is my asp.net mvc code I am using to retrieve date :

```
 if (scheduleresults.schedule_StartDate != null && scheduleresults.schedule_starttime != null)
                  {
                      sbs.Append("<td>" + scheduleresults.schedule_StartDate + scheduleresults.schedule_starttime + "</td>");
                  }
```

In above code, startdate contains date.

How do i put string format for above code ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I need to retrieve this date by removing zeros using string format
>   that is in below format : 04/02/2014.

This should work -

```
string date = "04/02/2014 00:00:00";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

will display - **04/02/2014**

> How do i put string format for above code ??

You should code something like this -

```
scheduleresults.schedule_StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

if it's a datetime object type you can do this

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");      
Console.WriteLine(thisDate.ToString("d", culture));  // Displays 15/3/2008
```

check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx